# Periodically getting image from PHP page

Tags: php, html, image

I have a PHP page, which gets arguments from URL and then generates image. I do not know what type of image (png, gif, etc.) it is. The normal use of this page is embeding the image in normal HTML page like this:

```
<img src="page.php?width=50&height=100">
```

This code would generate the image of height 100 and width 50.

The problem is: I want to periodically get that image from the page and save it on my server to a file. My original idea was to setup `cron` for `wget`, but `wget` downloads some bad things:

```
▒NB▒$l▒n▒▒N6E▒T`▒▒".▒*▒{F▒dY▒▒C▒1Ę▒▒(▒▒▒
```

(partial output of `cat`)

Was the idea good? If yes, how to get it working? If not, how would you do it?

One more requirement: I am not able to install extensions such as GD libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the correct way. The original idea was correct. I croned this script:

```
wget -O myfile.png "http://website/genimage.php?height=200&width=100"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to know the image type before you do this. You'll also want the GD libraries installed. I'm just going to guess it's a JPEG but you can change it to import the correct type of file

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://yoursite.com/page.php?width=50&height=100');
if($image) imagejpeg($image, '/path/to/save');
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention - I must be able to install it from my NAS administration. This will not work.